# How to listen to events inside the child component dispatched by the parent component

Tags: apache-flex, events

When an event is dispatched by a component, there are three phases in which the event flows, capture - event flows from the application to the component which dispatches the event, target when the event is at the Target which actually dispatches the event , then the bubbling phase in which the event flows from the target to the application. There is a situation in which Application has child comp1 , comp1 has child comp2. I have a button in the comp1 which dispatches the event and I want to listen to that event inside the comp2. Ideally the event would flow from Application->comp1->button->comp1->Application. How can I achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `comp1` dispatch your event and make sure it bubbles:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMyButtonClick);

private function handleMyButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
     dispatchEvent(new Event("myCustomEvent", true));
}
```

Now inside `comp2` listen for this event on the `stage`:

```
stage.addEventListener("myCustomEvent", handleMyCustomEvent);
```

That's it: because the event bubbles, it will *always* at some point hit the `stage`. So you can use it to listen from anywhere. Just don't forget to make sure the `stage` property of `comp2` is set before you try to attach a listener.

Note: be aware that all components in your application will be able to *see* this event, so make sure that the right component handles the right event. For starters I would never use this approach with built-in events; only use custom events whose `type`s do not coincide with the built-in ones.

Comment: If something else dispatches that same event, comp1 will hear that as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you're suggesting is probably not the best way to go about it. You should probably handle this better by having the parent explicitly do something that helps the child know what to do.

One way to do this is to use the concept of an event bus, such as [what you see in RobotLegs](http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/discussions/questions/495-why-a-centralized-event-bus). Just give your child2 a public field or property called `eventBus` with a type of IEventDispatcher. You can then have the parent populate this property with `this`. I usually set such properties up as getters/setters, so that the property can be nulled when the child is removed from the stage and the child can [remove its listeners](http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html).

This lets you start with exactly what you need to make this happen, but if you discover yourself using child2 in a situation where you need it to listen to a different object, you're ready to go.

A second possibility is to just expose a method on the child that the parent can call (the parent already has a reference to the child--you're not introducing unnecessary coupling here), and simply call it instead of dispatching the event.

Comment: Agreed on the first approach. I usually do something similar too, but I thought I'd give a simpler answer to start with. IMO the second approach does create coupling in the views' hierarchical structure. If I ever wanted to move `comp2` to another location (say I want to refactor it so that it is nested inside another custom component), that would break the code.

Comment: True, but you probably already have a variable that references it anyway, that would have to be stripped out. So there's additional work in moving that component either way. The important thing is that the component itself doesn't need to change. But I agree that the event bus is the way to go, and your suggestion could even be implemented this way to start and then be changed later.